# Pandas: Unpacking a list of dictionaries in cell to columns

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have the following data frame

```
d = {'id': {0: 'f0c92a3d-e845-446d-b802-704fcdc1ca94',
  1: '2c5ce4ff-aee3-4b45-8783-bb44b5d75fb3'},
  'usd_value': {0: 315574704.6100155,
  1: 267332059.93445513},

 'purchases': {0: [{'name': 'toy1',
    'symbol': 't1',
    'price': 9664},
   {'name': 'toy2',
    'symbol': 't2',
    'price': 8730}],
  1: [{'name': 'toy1',
    'symbol': 't1',
    'price': 5266},
   {'name': 'toy2',
    'symbol': 't2',
    'price': 107675},
   {'name': 'toy3',
    'symbol': 't3',
    'price': 106994}],
  }}

>>> pd.DataFrame(d)

    id                                      usd_value       purchases
0   f0c92a3d-e845-446d-b802-704fcdc1ca94    3.155747e+08    [{'name': 'toy1', 'symbol': 't1', 'price': 966...
1   2c5ce4ff-aee3-4b45-8783-bb44b5d75fb3    2.673321e+08    [{'name': 'toy1', 'symbol': 't1', 'price': 5...
```

I would like to unpack the list of dictionaries in the `purchases` column into separate columns called `name`, `symbol`, `price`.

Note that each id may have a different number of purchases (i.e. length of the list of dictionaries may be different). I would like to have the `id` and `use_value` for each of the purchase items repeated. I would like the new data frame to look like this

```
    id                                      usd_value       name    symbol price
0   f0c92a3d-e845-446d-b802-704fcdc1ca94    3.155747e+08    toy1    t1     9664
1   f0c92a3d-e845-446d-b802-704fcdc1ca94    3.155747e+08    toy2    t2     8730
```

I am having a bit of trouble unpacking it because the column is a list of dicts.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df2 = df.explode('purchases').reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df2['purchases'].values)
df2.join(df3).drop(columns = ['purchases'])
```

you get

```
     id                                     usd_value    name   symbol  price
0   f0c92a3d-e845-446d-b802-704fcdc1ca94    3.155747e+08    toy1    t1  9664
1   f0c92a3d-e845-446d-b802-704fcdc1ca94    3.155747e+08    toy2    t2  8730
2   2c5ce4ff-aee3-4b45-8783-bb44b5d75fb3    2.673321e+08    toy1    t1  5266
3   2c5ce4ff-aee3-4b45-8783-bb44b5d75fb3    2.673321e+08    toy2    t2  107675
4   2c5ce4ff-aee3-4b45-8783-bb44b5d75fb3    2.673321e+08    toy3    t3  106994
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df['purchases'])
```

Comment: This is the error I was getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df = df.explode('purchases') #unnest the list
pd.concat([df.drop(['purchases'], axis=1), df['purchases'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1) #unpack the dictionary
```